# error 16550 : "not authorized for query on " mongolab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mlab

I have a Rails application running on heroku and i am connecting at two dbs hosted in mongolab (X and Y).

I have configured two heroku env variables containing the connection strings. 
When i query on Y all works fine but when i query on X db it gives me the error 16550 : "not authorized for query on X.table".

I have setted up correctly both env variables for these connections and also have a valid user to access X db.

If i connect with the shell all works fine.

How can i solve this?

Here is the error message in rails:

```
{"status":"500",
"error":"The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Query\n  @length=88\n  @request_id=4\n  @response_to=0\n  
@op_code=2004\n  @flags=[:slave_ok]\n  
@full_collection_name=\"X.table\"\n  
@skip=0\n  @limit=0\n  
@selector={\"_id\"=>\"5252c92521e4af681a000002\"}\n  
@fields=nil>\n
failed with error 16550: \"not authorized for query on X.table\"\n\n
See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md\nfor details about this error."}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, if someone comes here with the same problem : look at your table model, if as in my case it is "stored_in" another database you must specify there the session of the the uri = evn variables on datbase.yml